# Screen sharing screen does not display after choosing screen using Reactjs and WebRTC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc

I can click the share screen and choose screens that I want but nothing displays in the video after I clicked it.

I want to display the screen that I have clicked or choose.

Share screen function:

```
const shareScreen = () => {
  var displayMediaStreamConstraints = {
    video: true // or pass HINTS
    };
    
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaStreamConstraints);
    } else {
        navigator.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaStreamConstraints);
    }
};
```

Video component

```
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                    <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>{name || 'Name'}</Typography>
                    <video playsInline muted ref={myVideo} autoPlay className={classes.video} />
                </Grid>
                 <button onClick={shareScreen}>Share Screen</button>
            </Paper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDisplayMedia` doesn't display anything, it returns a promise that resolves to a stream.  In order to display the video, you need to wait for the promise to resolve then assign the stream to the `srcObject` field of an `HTMLVideoElement`.

```
let video = document.getElementById('uservideo');
let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints);
video.srcObject = stream;
```

Comment: just want to ask, is there a way to see my share screen to the other user? because right now the page who got the share screen has the only visibility to it, while the 2nd page does not have the visibility to the share screen

Comment: Here's the link to my new question, if you can help me with this final piece. Thank you. [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821703/is-there-a-way-for-the-other-user-to-see-my-share-screen-react-and-webrtc)